# Отправка данных форм ссылкой с помощью js/jquery

Tags: jquery, html, php, javascript

Как отправить данные формы POST запросом ссылкой.

Т.е. вместо `<input type="submit" />`. Нужно `<a>` с каким-то onclick. Вообще желательно, если данные будут отправляться в том случае, если ссылке присвоен какой-то класс, например .post, А дела будет выполнять jQuery

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно так

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#submit").click(function(){
          if($(this).hasClass("somecls"))
             $("#form").submit();
       })
    })
    </script>
    <form id="form" ..>
       <a id="submit" href="javascript:void(0)">afasf</a>

    </form>
```

Comment: Только я бы не мешал HTML и JS. Если уж используете jQuery, то в ссылке для атрибута href не надо прописывать javascript:void(0), а просто отменить действие по умолчанию:


  $("#submit").click(function(evt){
       evt.preventDefault();
       // и дальше код
   });

Comment: @валентина-предтеченская что-то я не понял немного. Ссылка, получается должна иметь и #submit, и .somecls?

Comment: В данном случае я повесила на ссылку id="submit" для того, чтобы проще было из JS ее выбрать, можно не определять id, а решить проблему как-то по-другому
А класс somecls нужен исходя из условия "Вообще желательно, если данные будут отправляться в том случае, если ссылке присвоен какой-то класс, например .post"
То есть, post = somecls =)

Answer (score 1):

Если в друг нужно будет просто данные аякс запросом при клике по тегу а кинуть на сервер. Возможно так будет даже круче.

```
<!-- Jquery уже подключен -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.post').click(function(){ // Слушаем клик по всем тегам где есть класс post
                $.get($(this).attr('href'),function(data){ // Отправляем запрос
                    alert('Ответ сервера: '+ data);
                });
                return false; // Чтобы заблокировать действие клика по ссылке. Если не сделать страницу перегрузит по новой ссылке.
            });
        });
    </script>

    <a class="post" href="/url.php?data=value">URL</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Synhronization</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>

 <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#loginForm').submit(function() {
         $('#output').html('Connecting....');
         var postTo = "http://91.228.199.95/ksiywFac63f2hs/login.php";
             $.post(postTo, { who: $('[name=who]').val(), pass: $('[name=pass]').val() },
                 function(data) {
                    if(data != "") {
                        //alert(data);
                        $('#output').html(data);
                    } else {
                        alert("Could not connect to server");
                    }
                 });

             return false;
         });
    });
 </script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="foo">

 <div data-role="header">
 <h1>Foo</h1>
 </div><!-- /header -->

 <div data-role="content">

 <p id="output"></p>
 <p>
 <form method="post" id="loginForm">
 Who: <input type="text" name="who"><br /><br />
 Pass: <input type="password" name="pass"><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Login">
 </form>
 </p>

 </div><!-- /content -->

 <div data-role="footer">
 <h4>Page Footer</h4>
 </div><!-- /header -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</body>
</html>
```